# Querying XML data stored in SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

My table is `XMLData` with an `XML` column `XMLField`.

The data in the column looks like this:

```
<table>
  <id>{9ebef1ed-51f6-4160-b342-40fd1bf311c5}</id>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="Batch" value="Test Batch 123" type="System.String" />
        <column name="PartNo" value="Sample123" type="System.String" />
        <column name="Note" value="Slight Color Variants" type="System.String" />
        <column name="ShipDate" value="05-August-2018" type="System.DateTime" />
        <column name="Qty" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="Batch" value="Second Batch" type="System.String" />
        <column name="PartNo" value="SampleXyz" type="System.String" />
        <column name="Note" value="Release Date TBD" type="System.String" />
        <column name="ShipDate" value="01-September-2018" type="System.DateTime" />
        <column name="Qty" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
  <key>DefaultKey</key>
  <total>0</total>
  <data />
  <parameters />
</table>
```

I would like to query Batch, PartNo, Note, ShipDate, Qty, DefaultKey and retrieve the values.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    Batch = XC.value('(column[@name="Batch"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    PartNo = XC.value('(column[@name="PartNo"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Note = XC.value('(column[@name="Note"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ShipDate = XC.value('(column[@name="ShipDate"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Qty = XC.value('(column[@name="Qty"]/@value)[1]', 'int'),
    DefaultKey = XC.value('(column[@name="DefaultKey"]/@value)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    dbo.XmlData
CROSS APPLY
    XmlField.nodes('/table/rows/row/columns') AS XT(XC)
```

It basically takes the `XmlField` column's XML, and gets a "virtual" table of XML fragments according to the XPath in the `.nodes()` expression. From there, it reaches into those XML fragments returned, and pulls out the individual values you're interested in.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: @PELASyS: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.